# Double linked list implementation

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I am having some syntax problems with a double linked list program I am writing for educational purposes. I have created a struct in my header file, and my main program seems to be alright, but implementing my functions in the .cpp file is giving me immense difficulty. I am having trouble discerning the three cases for inserting a record into the list. Specifically, allocating the memory, initializing the list head and tail, and the order of statements is confusing to me, as is passing a copy of the record to be added to my list.

My header file is as follows:

```
struct rec
{
   char * id;
   char firstname[15];
   char lastname[15];
   struct rec* prev;
   struct rec* next;
};


int AddItem ( rec r );
int DeleteItem ( char* delid );
void PrintList ( int order );
```

My .cpp file, which is where the difficulty lies, is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "list.h"
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

// These pointers refer to the head and tail of the list.
rec* first = NULL;
rec* last = NULL;

int AddItem( Rec r )
{

   rec* newRecEntry;
   rec* current = NULL;
   rec* previous = NULL;

   // Check for duplicate id
   current = first;
   while (current)
   {
     if( strcmp(current -> id, r.id) == 0)
      {
         return 0;
      }
     else
      // Create a new node
      {
         newRecEntry = new Rec;
         newRecEntry->id = new char[strlen(r.id)+1];
         strcpy(newRecEntry->id, r.id);
         strcpy(newRecEntry->firstname,r.firstname);
         strcpy(newRecEntry->lastname,r.lastname);
         newRecEntry->next = NULL;
         newRecEntry->prev = NULL;
      }
      // Find the appropriate position for the node and insert accordingly
      // Check to see if the list is empty
      if (first == NULL)
      {
         first = newRecEntry;
         last = newRecEntry;
      }
      else if ( r.lastname>last.lastname)
      {




      else
      {

   return 0;
}

/*int DeleteItem(char* ID)
```

I am supposed to be able to insert at the beginning, middle, and end of the list. Delete an item from the list based on the ID, and print the list in ascending or descending order based on user input, but I'd first simply like to handle the addition of items to said list.
My function definitions are as follows and also contains some errors

*lists.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "list.h"
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

// These pointers refer to the head and tail of the list.
   rec* first = NULL;
   rec* last = NULL;

int AddItem( Rec r )
{

   rec* newRecEntry;
   rec* current = NULL;
   rec* previous = NULL;

   // Check for duplicate id
   current = first;
   while (current)
   {
     if( strcmp(current -> id, r.id) == 0)
      {
         return 0;
      }
     else
     // Create a new node
      {
         newRecEntry = new Rec;
         newRecEntry->id = new char[strlen(r.id)+1];
         strcpy(newRecEntry->id, r.id);
         strcpy(newRecEntry->firstname,r.firstname);
         strcpy(newRecEntry->lastname,r.lastname);
         newRecEntry->next = NULL;
         newRecEntry->prev = NULL;
      }
      // Find the appropriate position for the node and insert accordingly
      // Check to see if the list is empty
      if (first == NULL)
      {
         first = newRecEntry;
         last = newRecEntry;
      }
      else if ( r.lastname>last.lastname)
      {




      else
      {

   return 0;
}

/*int DeleteItem(char* ID)
{
   rec
}
*/



/*void printList(int order)
{
loop
 {
   cout << ptr -> Id << " ";
   cout << ptr -> firstname << " ";
   cout << ptr -> lastname << " ";
   cout << ptr -> prev << " ";  // address of previous
   cout <<  ptr << " ";   // address of item
   cout << ptr -> next << " ";  //  address of next item
 }

}
```

Main is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "list.h"
#include <string.h>  // <string>

using namespace std;

void main (void)
{
   int choice, printorder;
   char idbuffer[100];
   rec r;


do
{
  cout << "Enter your choice 1 Add, 2 Delete, 3 Print, 0 quit "<<endl;
  cin >> choice;

   switch ( choice )
   {
      case 1:  //AddItem
         cout << "\nEnter ID ";
         cin >> idbuffer;

         r.id = idbuffer;
         cout << "\nFirst Name ";
         cin >> r.firstname;
         cout << "\nLast Name ";
         cin >>  r.lastname;
         if ( AddItem ( r ) )
         {
            cout << "\nSuccess!\n";
         }
         else
         {
            cout << "\nItem failed to be added\n";
         }

         break;
      case 2:  //Delete
         cout << "\nEnter id :";
         cin >> idbuffer;
         if ( DeleteItem ( idbuffer ) )
         {
            cout << "\nDelete OK\n";
         }
         else
         {
            cout << "\nDelete Failed for " << idbuffer;
         }
         break;
      case 3: // Print
        cout << "Enter order 0 - Ascending, 1 - Descending\n";
        cin >> printorder;
        PrintList (printorder);
        break;
      case 0:  // quit
         break;


      default: // bad choice
         break;
   } // end switch

}
while ( choice != 0 );// end do while
}  // end main
```

Comment: That's C code with some `cout` mixed in, not C++. If you want to use C++, you should use `std::string` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: @us2012 I have to use the mix of code for educational purposes. I'm aware this is C and potentially more difficult, but I have no other choice.

Comment: @Jin NO NO NO. There's nothing educational in mixing C and C++ :/

Comment: @us2012 While I appreciate your colorful, witty commentary on the nature of my assignment, I assure you I've researched, done my homework, and came to stack overflow because I know it's a terrific resource for budding programmers. Furthermore, if you're implying I haven't been trying for more time than I'd like to admit, you're mistaken.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I've wondered why we're using C and C++ since I began but again, I have no control here.

Comment: @Jin I was suspecting that you used the term "for educational purposes" to hide the fact that this is an assignment. I will delete my previous comment.

Comment: @us2012 I didn't mean to give the impression I was hiding the nature of the work. I don't expect to be given the answer and in fact want to simply understand, but the lectures have proven hard to follow as have the tutorials I've seen online.

Comment: I stared a proposal for a Q&A site for beginning programmers where questions like this should be dealt with in a positive spirit instead of the usual RTFM answers. Follow it if you like my idea http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52242/beginner-programmers?referrer=YHFcRobXPDGfDpFmz1HCvA2

Comment: @AxelOmega I'll follow it and perhaps ask a question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not seem like it, but even this function

```
int AddItem(Record entry)
{
   Record* newRecordPointer;
   newRecordPointer=new Record;
   strcpy(newRecordPointer->firstName,entry.firstName);
   strcpy(newRecordPointer->lastName,entry.lastName);
   newRecordPointer->ID=new char[strlen(entry.ID)+1];
   strcpy(newRecordPointer->ID, entry.ID);
   return 0;
}
```

is trying to do too many things.

Let's write the pseudocode description of adding an item to a list:

1. *create* a **new node**
2. *populate* the **new node** with the **values provided**
3. *attach* the **new node** to **the list**

I've marked the *verbs* and **nouns** involved, and you can already see one of the **nouns** is missing from your function. You're asking `AddItem` to add an item to a list ... but you don't give it a list to work on.

It's also useful to write out your expectations clearly:

1. before `AddItem` is called:

   - it needs a list to work on
   - we don't have a list container class, just the records, so we have to pass a `Record`
   - let's say we want to add our new item *after* the `Record` passed in
2. after `AddItem` is called:

   - whatever `Record` we passed in, its `Next` should point to the new node
   - the new node's `Previous` should point to the node passed in
   - etc. etc. (these are the standard doubly-linked list insertion behaviours)
3. note for later: we haven't described how we store an empty list

   - if it's a circular list, an empty list will be a `Record` whose `Next` and `Previous` members point to itself
   - if it's linear, they might both be NULL instead
   - it could just be a NULL pointer, but then adding the first node to an empty list needs more effort

So, let's say the minimal function that could possibly work is:

```
void AddItem(Record *insert_after, Record value)
{
    Record *new_node = CreateRecord();
    CopyRecordValues(new_node, &value);
    AttachAfter(insert_after, new_node);
}
```

Note that if we were writing real C++ the first two lines could just use the copy constructor `Record *new_node = new Record(value)`, but it will take more changes than that to reach idiomatic C++ code from where we started.

---

Now, given that, can you:

- implement those three functions? (`CreateRecord` and `CopyRecordValues` are already handled in your current code)
- write the equivalent pseudocode for your other operations, and translate it yourself?

Comment: I should perhaps supply my main program code, I'll append the original post to include it, but thank you for this. This is very helpful. The main program is supposed to take all of the record components and pass a copy of the record to the AddItem procedure, but you likely gathered that after viewing the newly included code.

Comment: Ah, so you have a global first & last. So, you can ignore the **list**  noun (you already have it), and add instead the _check for duplicate_ verb.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
int AddItem(Record entry);
```

To this:

```
Record* AddItem(Record entry, Record *insertion_point = NULL );
```

If `insertion_point` is `NULL`, you can assume that the `Record` is the beginning of a new list.

Now you have enough information to set `Next` and `Previous` pointers, and return the newly created node.

Comment: I've since made this change. Though I'm trying to include all three cases in the AddItem procedure. Could I use this to cover the other cases?